# I added the gem in rails, but it still says gem missing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, omniauth

I typed the following:

```
gem install omniauth
```

In my `environment.rb` file, I also have:

```
config.gem "omniauth"
```

However, I get these errors:

```
no such file to load -- omniauth/core
Missing these required gems:
  omniauth
```

I'm confused: I do a rake gems:install and don't get an error (I don't get a message back, either).  But then I try to run script/server and it says I need to do rake gems:install!

When I remove the config.gem "omniauth" from environment.rb, I get this:

```
c:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:443:in `load_missing_constant': unin
itialized constant OmniAuth (NameError)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now that Rails 3 is using bundler, you need to make it explicit that you want access to a specific gem in your app. To do this, go into your `Gemfile` (in the root directory of your project) add this line:

```
gem 'omniauth'
```

then run `bundle install` in the project directory, and you should be good to go. `bundle install` simply makes sure that all gems and dependencies are installed on the current system. Good luck!

Comment: This wasn't really the right answer, but is close: I installed bundler onto my Rails 2.3.x app and that seems to be better.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestions:

Do "gem list" and see if omniauth is listed there.
Do "gem env" and see where the gems are installed to and whether those locations are part of the gem paths.

Sorry can't be of more help right now..

Answer (score 1):

Strange. Not familliar with oauth myself but two things you could check:

First you can try

```
rake gems:install
```

in your app root. If all dependencies are properly installed it shouldn't report anything.

Second, you can go into the console and type

```
require 'omniauth'
```

and

```
require 'omniauth/core'
```

Does the module load? Can you use it from the console? Sometimes errors loading modules or dependencies don't show up when you start the server, but they do show up in the console.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I suspect it was a Rubygems problem.
All I had to do is switch to using **[rvm](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/)**.
It manages multiple ruby versions including their appropriate versions of Rubygems.
It downloads and builds the required ruby versions from source so be sure to install all the needed dependencies first.
That solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem with Rails 2.3. Using [bundler](http://gembundler.com/rails23.html) solved that.